# I am new to selenium.How should i check a list of webelements(which are numbers) are masked after the 4th character

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I use selenium java to verify that the data table are masked after the 4th character.
I have used the below code to extract the WebElements from the GUI.
List IDds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[1]"));

Example of data:
1111$$$$
2222$$

Answer (score 0):

Find all the elements you need in a loop, or give a CSS expression that returns a list of web elements:

```
WebElement myElm = driver.findElementByCSS("CSSExpression");
String text = myElm.getAttribute("Text");
// or
// String text = myElm.getAttribute("Value");
Char C = text.charAt(4);
if (C=='$')
// Good
else 
// bad
```

You can also find the first location in the string where you see `$` and make sure all the other chars are the same.